# Indexing one array by another in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a matrix **A** with some arbitrary values:

```
array([[ 2, 4, 5, 3],
       [ 1, 6, 8, 9],
       [ 8, 7, 0, 2]])
```

And a matrix **B** which contains indices of elements in A:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

How do I select values from **A** pointed by **B**, i.e.:

```
A[B] = [[2, 2, 4, 5],
        [1, 9, 8, 6],
        [2, 0, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

EDIT: `np.take_along_axis` is a builtin function for this use case implemented since `numpy` 1.15.  See @hpaulj 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050065/4427777) below for how to use it.

---

You can use [`NumPy's advanced indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],B]
```

One can also use `linear indexing` -

```
m,n = A.shape
out = np.take(A,B + n*np.arange(m)[:,None])
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: A
Out[40]: 
array([[2, 4, 5, 3],
       [1, 6, 8, 9],
       [8, 7, 0, 2]])

In [41]: B
Out[41]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])

In [42]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],B]
Out[42]: 
array([[2, 2, 4, 5],
       [1, 9, 8, 6],
       [2, 0, 7, 8]])

In [43]: m,n = A.shape

In [44]: np.take(A,B + n*np.arange(m)[:,None])
Out[44]: 
array([[2, 2, 4, 5],
       [1, 9, 8, 6],
       [2, 0, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: I don't get how these work... could you add some explanations?

Comment: @JasonS Basically using a range array along first axis to select one per along that axis for each element in `B`. The provided link should give all the details needed.

Comment: Hmm... well, that's fine but I look at the advanced indexing link and it doesn't make sense to me. I need to extend your example to an N-dimensional array where only the last index is applied, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

More recent versions have added a `take_along_axis` function that does the job:

```
A = np.array([[ 2, 4, 5, 3], 
              [ 1, 6, 8, 9], 
              [ 8, 7, 0, 2]])  
                                          
B = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 2], 
              [0, 3, 2, 1], 
              [3, 2, 1, 0]])     
                                        
np.take_along_axis(A, B, 1)  
                                       
Out[]: 
array([[2, 2, 4, 5],
       [1, 9, 8, 6],
       [2, 0, 7, 8]])
```

There's also a `put_along_axis`.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but another way of doing it using indices is:

```
A[np.indices(B.shape)[0], B]
```

output:

```
[[2 2 4 5]
 [1 9 8 6]
 [2 0 7 8]]
```

Comment: Very elegant way of doing it!

Answer (score -3):

Following is the solution using `for` loop:

```
outlist = []
for i in range(len(B)):
    lst = []    
    for j in range(len(B[i])):
        lst.append(A[i][B[i][j]])
    outlist.append(lst)
outarray = np.asarray(outlist)
print(outarray)
```

Above can also be written in more succinct list comprehension form:

```
outlist = [ [A[i][B[i][j]] for j in range(len(B[i]))]
                for i in range(len(B))  ]
outarray = np.asarray(outlist)
print(outarray)
```

Output:

```
[[2 2 4 5]
 [1 9 8 6]
 [2 0 7 8]]
```

Comment: The asker of the question is looking for a solution that uses simple slicing, not for loops.  Slicing is incredibly faster than for loops.