# using an numpy array as indices of the 2nd dim of another array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

For example, I have two numpy arrays,

```
A = np.array(
  [[0,1], 
   [2,3], 
   [4,5]])
B = np.array(
  [[1],
   [0],
   [1]], dtype='int')
```

and I want to extract one element from each row of `A`, and that element is indexed by `B`, so I want the following results:

```
C = np.array(
  [[1],
   [2],
   [5]])
```

I tried `A[:, B.ravel()]`, but it'll broadcast `B`, not what I want. Also looked into `np.take`, seems not the right solution to my problem.

However, I could use `np.choose` by transposing `A`,

```
np.choose(B.ravel(), A.T)
```

but any other better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37878946/190597

Comment: @unutbu Well sort of different here, as we are selecting one element per row as opposed to multiple elements per row in the linked previous question.

Comment: @Divakar: If the OP wants the 2D array, `C`, your answer on the linked page gives the desired result exactly.

Comment: @unutbu, the answer you linked use `np.take`, and I don't think it could fix my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy's purely integer array indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) -

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),B.ravel()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [57]: A
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [58]: B
Out[58]: 
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1]])

In [59]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),B.ravel()]
Out[59]: array([1, 2, 5])
```

Please note that if `B` is a `1D` array or a list of such column indices, you could simply skip the flattening operation with `.ravel()`.

Sample run -

```
In [186]: A
Out[186]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [187]: B
Out[187]: [1, 0, 1]

In [188]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),B]
Out[188]: array([1, 2, 5])
```

Comment: so no broadcasting at all?

Comment: Well you don't need broadcasting here, if I got the expected output correctly from the question. We are basically using integers at each dim, to select elements. We have the 2nd dim indices from `B`, so we just needed to create the corresponding ones for the first dim using `np.arange`. Hope that made sense!

Answer (score -1):

```
C = np.array([A[i][j] for i,j in enumerate(B)])
```