# Tensorflow: Selecting items from one tensor by another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have a value tensor and a reordering tensor. Reordering tensor gives ordering for each row in value tensor. How can I use this reordering tensor to actually reorder values in the value tensor.

This gives the desired result in numpy ([Indexing one array by another in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878946/indexing-one-array-by-another-in-numpy)):

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([
    [5,4,100],
    [10,20,500]
])
reorder_rows = np.array([
    [1,2,0],
    [0,2,1]
])


result = values[np.arange(values.shape[0])[:,None],reorder_rows]
print(result)

# [[  4 100   5]
#  [ 10 500  20]]
```

How can I do the same in tf?

I have tried to play with slicing and tf.gather_nd but can't make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([
    [5,4,100],
    [10,20,500]
])
reorder_rows = np.array([
    [1,2,0],
    [0,2,1]
])

import tensorflow as tf

values = tf.constant(values)
reorder_rows = tf.constant(reorder_rows, dtype=tf.int32)
x = tf.tile(tf.range(tf.shape(values)[0])[:,tf.newaxis], [1,tf.shape(values)[1]])
res = tf.gather_nd(values, tf.stack([x, reorder_rows], axis=-1))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `tf code` should give the same result:

```
values = tf.constant([
 [5,4,100],
 [10,20,500]
])
reorder_rows = tf.constant([
   [[0,1],[0,2],[0,0]],
   [[1,0],[1,2],[1,1]]
])
result = tf.gather_nd(values, reorder_rows)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
result.eval()

#Result
#[[  4, 100,   5],
#[ 10, 500,  20]]
```