# Multidimensional indexing across rows in numpy (avoiding broadcasting)

Tags: numpy

I am trying to index into a 2-dimensional numpy ndarray with another 2-dimensional numpy ndarray.

The effect I would like is for each row in the indexing array to select elements in the corresponding row of the array being indexed. That is, I would like row i or my indexing array to index elements of row i of the array being indexed (but no other rows).

Currently however, it seems that when I try to index into my array, the indexing array is being broadcast across every row of the array being indexed.

The arrays I am working with are a (3, 1001) array and a (3, 5) array. I am trying to index the (3, 1001) array with the (3, 5) array and select 5 elements from each 1001-dimensional row of the array being indexed.

For instance, here is the behavior I want:

```
predictions_val[0][top_5[0]]
array([ 0.00222665,  0.00606673,  0.03681596,  0.85334235,  0.01018796], dtype=float32)

predictions_val[1][top_5[1]]
array([ 0.00106781,  0.00407206,  0.026693  ,  0.90732217,  0.0234713 ], dtype=float32)

predictions_val[2][top_5[2]]
array([ 0.00112946,  0.0016792 ,  0.06700196,  0.00367496,  0.87981129], dtype=float32)
```

Here is the behavior I get when trying to index simultaneously:

```
predictions_val[:,top_5]
array([[[  2.22665281e-03,   6.06672745e-03,   3.68159562e-02,
           8.53342354e-01,   1.01879649e-02],
        [  5.12826555e-05,   8.53342354e-01,   1.41255208e-03,
           2.77817919e-04,   1.01879649e-02],
        [  2.17145571e-04,   2.77817919e-04,   8.53342354e-01,
           1.41255208e-03,   1.01879649e-02]],

       [[  5.50073055e-05,   8.74355683e-05,   2.71841218e-05,
           4.07205941e-03,   2.34712958e-02],
        [  1.06781046e-03,   4.07205941e-03,   2.66929977e-02,
           9.07322168e-01,   2.34712958e-02],
        [  5.84539608e-04,   9.07322168e-01,   4.07205941e-03,
           2.66929977e-02,   2.34712958e-02]],

       [[  1.05086729e-04,   2.83752568e-04,   7.68712547e-04,
           6.70019612e-02,   8.79811287e-01],
        [  4.69864433e-04,   6.70019612e-02,   3.67495860e-03,
           1.67920033e-03,   8.79811287e-01],
        [  1.12945912e-03,   1.67920033e-03,   6.70019612e-02,
           3.67495860e-03,   8.79811287e-01]]], dtype=float32)
```

Each row that I want exists in the arrays that are returned but it seems that the top_5 array is being broadcast across very row.

Comment: See if this works for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878946/indexing-one-array-by-another-in-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correctly index your data. [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) can help for that :

```
pred=rand(3,1001)
top=randint(0,1001,(3,5))

I,J=indices(top.shape)
res=pred[I,top]
```

then `res[i]`  for `i in {0,1,2}` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something similar to below;

```
X = ... # your data, shape (3,1001)
idx = ... # the wanted indices, shape (3,5)

# reshape idx to (2,idx.shape[0]*idx.shape[1])
idx = np.array([[i,index] for i in range(X.shape[0]) for index in idx[i]]).tranpose()

Wanted = X[idx[0],idx[1]]
```

This will create an array, idx, where the first row is the wanted row in X, and the second row is the wanted column in X.