# index numpy two arrays

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays. I would like to use one of them as a reference for the second one, how can I do it?
I have the following array A:

```
A = np.array([[1.00, 0.0, 1.03, 1.18],
          [0.0, 1.58, 0.0, 7.59],
          [1.00, 1.22, 1.07, 1.03]])
```

In addition, I have the array B:

```
B = np.array([[1.00, 2.00, 27.00, 10.00],
          [3.00, 9.00, 6.00, 2.00],
          [2.00, 6.00, 4.00, 15.00]])
```

I need to identify the position/location (`[i,j]`) of all zeros in A by column (if you pass from array to dataframe-just to clarify my point), then go to B and perform a certain operation (sum, or any other math formula) in the same `[i,j]`. I dont know how to it with arrays.

What I did up to now: I could solve this building a new array (C) which have i-columns (viewed as a dataframe) from A and B, then deleted rows where the first column is zero and performed the operation (in a loop sequence). I know this is not the most efficient way to do it.
I also tried changing array to dataframe (then applied `loc`), but I prefer to use array for data manipulation. Finally, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878946/indexing-one-array-by-another-in-numpy) but the following message pops up `arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

I would like to learn a new approach to my task.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the certain operation? Also what do you mean by identify all zeros by column?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I edited the post to answer your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add what will be the output for your A matrix?

Comment: Do you want to count the columns where all the elements are zeros?

Comment: @DanielMesejo more details in the post. Thanks for your comments (they help me to clarfify even more what I am looking for)

Comment: I guess you should take a look at the answer by @tel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution: use a masked array

Considering the form of your `A` and `B`, the easiest way to do the calculations you want is via a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html). First, you create a new masked array with the data from `B`, masked at all of the locations where `A==0`:

```
marr = np.ma.masked_array(B, A==0)
print(f'the masked array looks like\n{marr}\n')
```

Output:

```
the masked array looks like
[[1.0 -- 27.0 10.0]
 [-- 9.0 -- 2.0]
 [2.0 6.0 4.0 15.0]]
```

### operate on all columns in masked array at once without a loop

You can then perform various operations (`sum`, `mean`, `cumprod`, etc) on all of the masked columns at once like so:

```
colsums = marr.sum(axis=0)
colmeans = marr.mean(axis=0)

print(f'sum of each masked column\n{colsums}\n')
print(f'the mean of each masked column\n{colmeans}\n')
```

Output:

```
sum of each masked column
[3.0 15.0 31.0 27.0]

the mean of each column
[1.5 7.5 15.5 9.0]
```

Note that the mean of the first column is calculated as `(1.0 + 2.0)/2`. The `mean` method ignores the masked element(s) completely, the same as in the OP's original row deletion approach.

### loop over the masked columns

If you instead want to perform some calculation for which there is no built-in Numpy method like `sum` or `mean`, you can instead iterate over the masked columns and operate on each in turn like so:

```
colmeans = [col.mean() for col in marr.T]
print(f'the result of iterating over the masked columns and taking the mean of each\n{colmeans}\n')
```

Output:

```
the result of iterating over the masked columns and taking the mean of each
[1.5, 7.5, 15.5, 9.0]
```