# How to concatenate dynamic slices of numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, slice

I have a TensorFlow layer that I'm using to create a 4d tensor called "cost_volume".

My code gets the job done. However, due to the nested for loops rather than using numpy built-in functions, it is rather slow. I need it to be at least 300x faster. How to convert this to more efficient code that uses numpy built in functions and no for loops?

```
max_disparity = 10
layer = np.random.rand(2, 188, 621, 32)
cost_volume = np.random.rand(layer.shape[0], layer.shape[1], layer.shape[2],\
                                 max_disparity + 1, feature_size * 2)

for i in range(layer.shape[0]):
    for y in range(layer.shape[1]):
        for x in range(layer.shape[2]):
            for d in range(max_disparity + 1):
                if i == 0:
                    cost_volume[i][y][x][d] = np.concatenate((layer[0][y][x], \
                                                         layer[1][y][min(x + d, layer.shape[2] - 1)]))
                else:
                    cost_volume[i][y][x][d] = np.concatenate((layer[0][y][max(0, x - d)], \
                                                         layer[1][y][x]))
```

Comment: you need to provide more information like, what is the shape of `layer` array?

Comment: (2, 188, 621, 32)

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of what you're trying to achieve? I have a hard time figuring out what the np.concatenates are aimed at.

Comment: We want to concatenate the two arrays, (features): [1 2 3], [4 5 6] -> [1 2 3 4 5 6]

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37878946/6692898) about how to slice arrays with another array/list

Answer (score 0):

ok, so tried to vectorize this code, and so far i'v come up with this

```
# just renaming some variables

Z = layer.shape[0]
Y = layer.shape[1]
X = layer.shape[2]
D = max_disparity + 1
F = feature_size

cost_volume = np.empty([Z, Y, X, D, F * 2])
```

actual code:

```
cost_volume[0, ..., :F] = layer[0, :,  :, None]               # i == 0 and 1st half of concatenate
cost_volume[0, ..., F:] = layer[1, :, -1, None, None]         # i == 0 and 2nd half of concatenate, default min(x + d, X) == X 

cost_volume[1, ..., F:] = layer[1, :,  :, None]               # i == 1 and 2nd half of concatenate  
cost_volume[1, ..., :F] = layer[0, :,  0, None, None]         # i == 1 and 1st half of concatenate, default max(x - d, 0) == 0
```

```
Xi, Di = np.ogrid[0:X, 0:D]        # indices used in 2nd and 3rd axis 

m1 = Xi + Di < X                   # positions where min(x + d, X) == x + d  ie where default doesnt apply 
m2 = Xi - Di > 0                   # positions where max(x - d, 0) == x - d  ie where default doesnt apply
```

```
cost_volume[0, :, m1, F:] = layer[1, :, (Xi + Di)[m1]]   # updating cost values where defaults should not apply
cost_volume[1, :, m2, :F] = layer[0, :, (Xi - Di)[m2]]
```

i've tried my best to make the code self explanitory and if it does'nt work then let me know

Comment: This code gives: 
cost_volume[0, ..., :F] = layer[0]                # i == 0 and 1st half of concatenate
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (188,621,32) into shape (188,621,11,32)

Comment: That gives:
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array([  0,   1,   2, ..., 619, 620, 620])

Comment: @zendevil is `layer` a `tf.Tensor` object? if so then you need to convert it to an `np.array` before the last two lines of code

Comment: This code runs >300x faster, although the ogrid index is 0:D+1. Would you please give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: @zendevil i'll be happy to explain more, and if my answer helped you please accept it by selecting the green tick next to it

Comment: @zendevil where do you need more explaintion?

Comment: I tried to compare this to my solution but it raises "could not broadcast input array from shape (188,621,1,32) into shape (188,621,11,2)" on the first line after np.empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using numpy's [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html?highlight=advanced%20indexing#advanced-indexing). It has the advantage of not copying data until the very last line.

Take the array

```
max_disparity = 10
feature_size = 2
np.random.seed(123)
layer = np.random.rand(2, 188, 621, 32)
```

And the code

```
I, Y, X, D, F = layer.shape[:-1] + (max_disparity + 1, feature_size)
left = ( ### tuple of index-arrrays for left side of concat
    np.zeros((I, Y, X, D), dtype=int), # index for axis 0
    np.array([[[[y for d in range(D)] for x in range(X)]
        for y in range(Y)] for i in range(I)]), # index for axis 1
    np.array([[[[x if i==0 else max(0, x-d) for d in range(D)] for x in range(X)]
        for y in range(Y)] for i in range(I)]), # index for axis 2
    )
right = ( ### tuple of index-arrrays for right side of concat
    np.ones((I, Y, X, D), dtype=int), # index for axis 0
    np.array([[[[y for d in range(D)] for x in range(X)]
        for y in range(Y)] for i in range(I)]), # index for axis 1
    np.array([[[[min(x+d, X-1) if i==0 else x for d in range(D)] for x in range(X)]
        for y in range(Y)] for i in range(I)]), # index for axis 2
    )
### now slice layer with both tuples and concatenate inner-most dim
cost_volume = np.concatenate([layer[left], layer[right]], axis=-1)
```

It took 41.2s on my laptop with 2.16 GHz dual core Celeron and 4 GB

Comment: couldn't compare to your code as it raises 'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64) into shape (4)' on the first concat line