# How to create an NumPy array based on the index stored in another array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let say I have this NumPY array

```
A =
array([[0, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 4]])
```

I have another array

```
B =
array([[10, 41, 26, 50, 12, 24],
       [20, 15, 42, 40, 41, 62]])
```

I wanted to create another array, where it selects the element in B using the index of the column in A. That is

```
C =
array([[10, 41, 50],
       [15, 42, 41]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indexing one array by another in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878946/indexing-one-array-by-another-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
B[[[0],[1]], A]
```

Or more generally:

```
B[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], A]
```

Output:

```
array([[10, 41, 50],
       [15, 42, 41]])
```

Comment: What [:,None] is for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [np.take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis)

```py
np.take_along_axis(B, A, axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[10, 41, 50],
       [15, 42, 41]])
```

Comment: This looks simple. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done using list rather than numpy
Though, in the ending we can convert it into numpy.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
#to make it simpler take a 1d list

a = [0,1,3]
b = [10, 41, 26, 50, 12, 24]

c = []

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)


#here we are using for loop to find the value in a and append the index of b in c
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(i)
  i = a[i]
  c.append(b[i])

print(c)

c = np.array(c)
print(type(c))

#To make it more fun, you can use the random module to get random digits
```

Comment: Check the other snswers to see how easy it is with numpy.